# Refilling an existing numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a efficient way to refill a numpy array with a sequence of numbers in Python without recreating it?  Suppose, for example, that I create an array using the linspace function

```
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10000)
```

and later I want to change the array x so that it spans a different range.  If I write

```
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 10000)
```

I destroy the old array and create a new one.  This seems like a big waste of computer time.  So, is there an *efficient* way of filling the already existing array x with the new sequence without recreating the array?

Comment: There's no general way to do this without constructing the new array. But unless you're doing that in a tight loop, it shouldn't really matter. Is there a specific piece of code that you're trying to optimize?

Comment: 'This seems like a big waste of computer time': did you actually measure that by profiling your code? If not, this is a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the old array by 5 and then multiply it by 6. But due to numerical instabilities, it won't be the exact same values:

```
>>> x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
>>> x
array([-5.        , -3.88888889, -2.77777778, -1.66666667, -0.55555556,
        0.55555556,  1.66666667,  2.77777778,  3.88888889,  5.        ])
>>> y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 10)
>>> y
array([-6.        , -4.66666667, -3.33333333, -2.        , -0.66666667,
        0.66666667,  2.        ,  3.33333333,  4.66666667,  6.        ])
>>> z = (x / 5.) * 6.
>>> z
array([-6.        , -4.66666667, -3.33333333, -2.        , -0.66666667,
        0.66666667,  2.        ,  3.33333333,  4.66666667,  6.        ])
>>> z == y
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

And by the way, I tested your hypothesis and it holds true:

```
>>> def f():
...     t = datetime.datetime.now()
...     for i in range(10000):
...             a = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10000)
...             a = np.linspace(-6, 6, 10000)
...     dt1 = datetime.datetime.now() - t
...     t = datetime.datetime.now()
...     for i in range(10000):
...             a = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10000)
...             a *= 1.2
...     dt2 = datetime.datetime.now() - t
...     return dt1, dt2
... 
>>> a, b = f()
>>> a > b
True
>>> print a, b
0:00:01.020487 0:00:00.599225
```

Comment: With `z = (x / 5.) * 6`, you are creating two new arrays in memory (first `temp = x / 5`, then `z = temp * 6`), so this might be even slower than just calling linspace again. A better way would be to use in-place multiplication: `y *= 6. / 5.`. This does not allocate any new array, but has the same problem of small numerical errors.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, it's better to do it in place. I just did it this way so I could do the comparison in the end and show the slight variation in the results.